# Facing CORS policy or 404 not found vuejs and socket.io with npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, webpack, socket.io, cors, vue-cli-3

I'm actually developing on my local machine.

I have a simple socket.io server running on my local machine:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')();
io.listen(3000);
```

On my Vue-js application, I want to connect a socket.io-client

```js
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
const io = socketio('http://localhost');
```

I run my serve with : `npm run serve`

And in my console is writing:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M_JIr4_' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to set my vue.config.js file like this:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    // options...
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost/',
    }
  }
```

And my client like this:

```js
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
const io = socketio('http://localhost:8080');
```

It removes the CORS but then I get this in the console:

> GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M_JLsr5 404 (Not Found)

Is there a way to make it works on the localhost?

PS: I generated my project with @vue/cli

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it can help someone else:

I reboot my computer, deleted `vue.config.js` and replaced

```
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
const io = socketio('http://localhost');
```

by

```
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
const io = socketio('http://localhost:3000');
```

Looking like it solved my problem.